# Can't get site.baseurl to work in jekyll

Tags: web-deployment, jekyll, github-pages

I'm creating a GitHub project page with Jekyll.

I've read the previous questions on this subject, as well as the [Jekyll documentation here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/).

I've tried setting baseurl in `_config.yml` to both `/my-project` 
and 
`http://myaccount.github.io/my-project` while linking my CSS and js files like so:

```
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/js/javascript.js"></script>
<link href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I run `jekyll --serve --baseurl ''` everything looks good on localhost.

But when I push to github, all of my CSS and js files are 404ing; the links are getting turned into `http://css/style.css` and so on.

What am I missing here?

I'm also confused about the purpose of the `BASE_PATH` variable in `_config.yml`, as opposed to `baseurl`.

I tried setting `BASE_PATH` and linking my files that way, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out -- `baseurl` wasn't getting parsed because I had mistakenly placed it under the `JB:` hash in `_config.yml`. I moved `baseurl` to a different part of the file and it's working properly now.

Answer (score 1):

try using `baseurl` instead. That's what I use.

see https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/default/

Comment: Do you mean {{ site.url}} instead of {{ site.baseurl}} to get the baseurl in Jekyll? Not working. I want to get the name of localhost in my local and tik9.github.io in my remote env.

Comment: looks like the api has changed since I wrote that. `baseurl` should be it. You are editing the `_config.yml` file?

Comment: No, I want to have the hostname, in php: gethostname();

Answer (score 0):

You can try and create a new variable in the config file,

```
newbaseurl: /
```

and use it instead of baseurl, this seemed to fix my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar issue by changing site.baseurl to relative_url as per: [Jekyll site works locally but not on Github Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450554/jekyll-site-works-locally-but-not-on-github-pages/47530487#47530487)

Trying `newbaseurl: /` did not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had a same issue and I created a new variable in inside _config.yml

```
resource: https://name.github.io/myapp
```

Then I used that variable like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/style.css"  | prepend:site.resource}}">
```

Also please remember to build before push to the remote. Run this to build

```
jekyll build
```